# HTML Table gets randomly "unsorted", dont know why

Tags: javascript, html, mongodb, meteor

## Problem

I am making a Meteor.js app, and are importing .csv files via Papaparse.js, which I save in a Mongo collection for later use in a table. The data is saved in a standard Papaparse.js structure:

```
results = {
  data: [ ... ],    // parsed data
  errors: [ ... ],  // errors encountered
  meta: {   ... }     // extra parse info
}
```

The data array looks like this (from Chrome console):
[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Bumgz.png)

I output this in a front-end view, where this data is shown as a table. But sometimes, the data gets all unsorted. This often happens if I move the DB to another server or import the DB to local. Look at this image for a comparison: [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uWdM9.png)

**The question is why, and *how* I can fix it.**

This is my table template:
(note that projectData.data is from Iron Router, which is the Papaparse data (results.data))

```
<template name="table">
    <div class="table-responsive">
        <table class="table table-striped table-hover sortable-theme-bootstrap table-fixedheader" data-sortable>
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    {{#each addStatusColToArray projectData.meta.fields}}
                        <th>{{this}}</th>
                    {{/each}}
                    <th class="data-controls-header"></th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>

                {{#each projectData.data}}
                    <tr>
                        {{#each tableObjectToKeyPairs this}}
                            <td class="{{key}}">
                                {{value}}
                            </td>
                        {{/each}}
                        <td class="data-controls">
                            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-menu-right" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                {{/each}}


            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>
</template>
```

And this is the corresponding JS file:

```
Template.embedTable.helpers({
    rowClassPropId: function (parentContext) {

        var colLink = parentContext.projectData.meta.colLink;
        var propId = this[colLink];

        return propId;
    },
    tableObjectToKeyPairs: function (object) {

        var filteredObject = _.omit(object, "_id"); // Omit the "_id" value

        return _.map(filteredObject, function (value, key) {

            return {
                key: key,
                value: value
            };

        });
    }
});

Template.registerHelper("addStatusColToArray", function (array) {

    if (array) {
        array.push("Status"); // Pushes the "Status" last into array
        return array; // Returns the modified array
    }

});
```

Comment: One clue is that in your incorrect example almost all the columns show a sort indicator (down triangle icon).

Comment: Can we see template's JS?

Comment: No problem, I have added it now. :-) @Tdm